# SQLAlchemy. 2 different relationships for 1 column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a simple many-to-many relationship with associated table: 
[image]

with following data:

matches:[image]
users:[image]

users_mathces:[image]

ONE user can play MANY matches
and
ONE match can involve up to TWO users
I want to realize proper relationships in both "Match" and "User" classes

```
users_matches_table = Table('users_matches', Base.metadata,
    Column('match_id', Integer, ForeignKey('matches.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE")),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id', onupdate="CASCADE", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    )

class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'matches'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    #relations
    user1 = relationship('User', secondary = users_matches_table)
    user2 = relationship('User', secondary = users_matches_table)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)

    #relations
    matches = relationship('Match', secondary=users_matches_table)
```

But obviously, there should be some rules for Match.user1 and Match.user2 relationships, that will differ one User from another, so i could get `match1.user1` and `match1.user2` and they won't reference to the same User.
Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do it like this. I suggest you have just one relationship `users` and validate the insert queries.